# Uncertain and Incorrect returning result of FastCollinearPoints algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working with fast find collinear points problem that use merge-sort for sorting the line segments. Basically, the algorithm works like this:

```
Given a point p, the following method determines whether p participates in a set of 4 or more collinear points.

Think of p as the origin. 

For each other point q, determine the slope it makes with p.

Sort the points according to the slopes they makes with p. 

Check if any 3 (or more) adjacent points in the sorted order have equal slopes with respect to p. 

If so, these points, together with p, are collinear.
```

Here is my data-structure implements the algorithm:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

public class FastCollinearPoints {
    private LineSegment[] segments;

    public FastCollinearPoints(Point[] points) 
    {
        
      
        checkNull(points);
        checkDuplicate(points);

        Point[] pointsCopy = Arrays.copyOf(points, points.length);
        Arrays.sort(pointsCopy);

        ArrayList<LineSegment> segmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsCopy.length - 3; i++) 
        {
            Point p = pointsCopy[i];
            Point[] sortedPoints = Arrays.copyOfRange(pointsCopy, i + 1, pointsCopy.length);
            // Sort the remaining points based on their slopes to the reference point p
            Arrays.sort(sortedPoints, p.slopeOrder());

            int currentStartIndex = 0;
            double currentSlope = p.slopeTo(sortedPoints[currentStartIndex]);

            for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedPoints.length; j++) 
            {
                Point currentStartPoint = sortedPoints[currentStartIndex];

                Point currentPoint = sortedPoints[j];


                 if (currentPoint == null || currentStartPoint == null) 
                 {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate points found");
               }


                double slopeToP = p.slopeTo(currentPoint);
                
                if (Double.compare(slopeToP, currentSlope) != 0) 
                {
                     // Check if the adjacent points form a line segment
                    if (j - currentStartIndex >= 3 && currentStartPoint.compareTo(p) >= 0) 
                    {   
                        Point[] segmentPoints = Arrays.copyOfRange(sortedPoints, currentStartIndex, j);
                        Arrays.sort(segmentPoints);
                        segmentList.add(new LineSegment(p, segmentPoints[segmentPoints.length - 1]));
                       
                    }
                    currentStartIndex = j;
                    currentSlope = slopeToP;
                }
        }
            
             // Check if the last set of points forms a segment
             if (sortedPoints.length - currentStartIndex >= 3) 
             
            {
                Point[] segmentPoints = Arrays.copyOfRange(sortedPoints, currentStartIndex, sortedPoints.length);
                Arrays.sort(segmentPoints);
                segmentList.add(new LineSegment(p, segmentPoints[segmentPoints.length - 1]));
            }
             
        }
           
          segments = segmentList.toArray(new LineSegment[0]);
    }

       
   


    public int numberOfSegments() {
        return segments.length;
    }

    public LineSegment[] segments() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(segments, segments.length);
    }

    private void checkNull(Point[] points) {
        if (points == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("points cannot be null");
             }

     for (Point p : points) {
           if (p == null) {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("points cannot contain null entries");
                 }
             }
    }

    private void checkDuplicate(Point[] points) {
        Point[] pointsCopy = Arrays.copyOf(points, points.length);
        Arrays.sort(pointsCopy);

        Point currentPoint = pointsCopy[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < pointsCopy.length; i++) {
            if (pointsCopy[i].compareTo(currentPoint) == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate points found");
            } else {
                currentPoint = pointsCopy[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // read the n points from a file
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        int n = in.readInt();
        Point[] points = new Point[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = in.readInt();
            int y = in.readInt();
            points[i] = new Point(x, y);
        }

        // draw the points
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, 32768);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 32768);
        for (Point p : points) {
            p.draw();
        }
        StdDraw.show();

        // print and draw the line segments
        FastCollinearPoints collinear = new FastCollinearPoints(points);
        for (LineSegment segment : collinear.segments()) {
            StdOut.println(segment);
            segment.draw();
        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }
}
```

Below are some samples of the input that I fed the code :

```
equidistant.txt

15
10000 0
8000 2000
2000 8000
0  10000

20000 0
18000 2000
2000 18000

10000 20000
30000 0
0 30000
20000 10000

13000 0
11000 3000
5000 12000
9000 6000

the result I got :
(10000, 0) -> (0, 10000)
(10000, 0) -> (30000, 0)
(13000, 0) -> (5000, 12000)
(30000, 0) -> (0, 30000)
```

```
input8.txt

8
10000      0
    0  10000
 3000   7000
 7000   3000
20000  21000
 3000   4000
14000  15000
 6000   7000

the result i got:

(10000, 0) -> (0, 10000)
(3000, 4000) -> (20000, 21000)
```

And when I give my code to the auto-grader which assert my code is incorrect, but the result is not enough for me to understand where the code wrong and how the full correct result should look like:

```
 * filename = input8.txt
    - segments() contains a subsegment of a segment in reference solution
    - student   segment 3: (6000, 7000) -> (20000, 21000)
    - reference segment 1: (3000, 4000) -> (6000, 7000) -> (14000, 15000) -> (20000, 21000)

    - number of entries in student   solution: 4
    - number of entries in reference solution: 2
    - 4 extra entries in student solution, including:
      '(6000, 7000) -> (20000, 21000)'

    - 2 missing entries in student solution, including:
      '(3000, 4000) -> (6000, 7000) -> (14000, 15000) -> (20000, 21000)'


  * filename = equidistant.txt
    - segments() contains a subsegment of a segment in reference solution
    - student   segment 0: (10000, 0) -> (13000, 0)
    - reference segment 3: (10000, 0) -> (13000, 0) -> (20000, 0) -> (30000, 0)

    - number of entries in student   solution: 11
    - number of entries in reference solution: 4
    - 11 extra entries in student solution, including:
      '(20000, 10000) -> (2000, 18000)'

    - 4 missing entries in student solution, including:
      '(30000, 0) -> (20000, 10000) -> (10000, 20000) -> (0, 30000)'
```

I wonder what part in my nested loop (belongs to the FastCollinearPoints method) caused the code failed the test, and how I should modify the data-structure to get the correct result ?

`What I had tried: I have tried to modify the condition of the nested loop, but it still keep return the same result, i expected the line segment should contain vertical line segments (same x coordinate), which the code cannot handle correctly.`

Thanks !

`Addition: For anyone want to know what is the Point class and LineSegment class should look like here it is`

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
   private final int x; // x coordinate
    private final int y; // y coordinate
    

    public Point(int x, int y) {
     // constructs the point (x, y)
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }           

    public void draw()  {
        StdDraw.point(x, y); // draws the point
    }      
    

    public void drawTo(Point that) {
        if (this.y == that.y) {
            // Draw a vertical line
            StdDraw.line(this.x, this.y, that.x, that.y + 1);
        } else 
        StdDraw.line(this.x,this.y,that.x,that.y);   // draws the line segment from this point to that point
    }                 
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")" ;  // string representation       
    }                         
 
    public  int compareTo(Point that)
        // compare two points by y-coordinates, breaking ties by x-coordinates
    {   
        if (this.y < that.y) return -1; // this.y < that.y
        else if (this.y > that.y) return 1; // this.y > that.y
        else if (this.x < that.x) return -1; //  this.x < that.x
        else if (this.x > that.x) return 1; // this.x > that.x
       
        else return 0;     
    }
    public double slopeTo(Point that) {
        // the slope between this point and that point

        if (that == null) {
           throw new NullPointerException("The argument to the method is null");
        }
       
        int deltaX = that.x - this.x ; 
        int deltaY = that.y - this.y;

        if (this.x == that.x) {
            if (this.y == that.y) {
            return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY; // Degenerate line segment (between a point and itself)
        } else  {
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // Vertical line segment
        } 

    }
        else if (this.y == that.y) { 
           return 0.0; // Horizontal line segment
        }
        return (double) deltaY / deltaX; // Calculate the slope   
    }    

    public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder()  {
        return new SlopeOrder(this); // return a comparator object
    }
    private class SlopeOrder implements Comparator<Point> {
        private Point referencePoint;

        public SlopeOrder(Point r) {
            this.referencePoint = r;
        }

        public int compare(Point p, Point q) {

            if (p == null || q == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Arguments cannot be null");
            }
            
            double slope1 = referencePoint.slopeTo(p);
            double slope2 = referencePoint.slopeTo(q);

            if (Double.isInfinite(slope1) && Double.isInfinite(slope2) &&((slope1 > 0 && slope2 > 0)||(slope1 < 0 && slope2 < 0))) {
                return 0; // slopes are both infinity
            }
            if (Double.isInfinite(slope1) && Double.isInfinite(slope2) && slope1 < 0 && slope2 > 0) {
                return -1;  
            } else if (Double.isInfinite(slope1) && Double.isInfinite(slope2) && slope1 > 0 && slope2 < 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (slope1 < slope2) {
                 return -1; // slopeToP is less than slopeToQ
             } else if (slope1 > slope2) {
                return 1;  // slopeToP is greater than slopeToQ
             } else {
                return 0; //Points are collinear
            }  // check for antisymetric and transitive comparision
            
            }
         
     }  
    }
```

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac LineSegment.java
 *  Execution:    none
 *  Dependencies: Point.java
 *
 *  An immutable data type for Line segments in the plane.
 *  For use on Coursera, Algorithms Part I programming assignment.
 *
 *  DO NOT MODIFY THIS CODE.
 *
 *************************************************************************/

 public class LineSegment {
    private final Point p;   // one endpoint of this line segment
    private final Point q;   // the other endpoint of this line segment

    /**
     * Initializes a new line segment.
     *
     * @param  p one endpoint
     * @param  q the other endpoint
     * @throws NullPointerException if either <tt>p</tt> or <tt>q</tt>
     *         is <tt>null</tt>
     */
    public LineSegment(Point p, Point q) {
        if (p == null || q == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument to LineSegment constructor is null");
        }
        if (p.equals(q)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("both arguments to LineSegment constructor are the same point: " + p);
        }
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }

    
    /**
     * Draws this line segment to standard draw.
     */
    public void draw() {
        p.drawTo(q);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this line segment
     * This method is provide for debugging;
     * your program should not rely on the format of the string representation.
     *
     * @return a string representation of this line segment
     */
    public String toString() {
        return p + " -> " + q;
    }

    /**
     * Throws an exception if called. The hashCode() method is not supported because
     * hashing has not yet been introduced in this course. Moreover, hashing does not
     * typically lead to good *worst-case* performance guarantees, as required on this
     * assignment.
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if called
     */
    public int hashCode() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("hashCode() is not supported");
    }
}
```

I haven't use the hash map to handle my line segment class, because the API I used will throw an exception if I work with it, but should the hash map be a better alteration to solve the problem ?

Comment: You haven't provided your `Point` or `LineSegment` classes, although the latter may be trivial, but the implementations of `Point::slopeOrder` and `Point::slopeTo` may be critical to understanding the issue. (I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: In the output from the "auto-grader" you have shown, it always shows reference segments and missing entries with more than two points, but your segments in your results always contain two and only two points.

Comment: Making assumptions about `Point`, I have a version of it where instead of looping over sub-arrays of points, I categorize them with `Arrays.stream(points).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> p.slopeTo(s)));`. This gives a map from slope to lists of points with that slope w.r.t. `p`. Any such group of size 3 or larger is a solution, along with p. You can put these solutions into a set to ensure you only identify each unique solution once, and sort them by their smallest point to output them in a canonical order.

Comment: @DavidConrad I had added my version of my ```Point``` and ```LineSegment``` classes to my question so you view it now. It kinda different from your version, (I don't use hash map for handling the line segments). But thanks for your answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had a couple of other thoughts that might help you. You might want to try with a simple test case that you know will be collinear, like (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4). You might also want to run your program under a debugger or add print statements and verify at various points that the intermediate results are what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following helper class:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class Points implements Comparable<Points> {
    private List<Point> points;

    public Points(Collection<Point> points) {
        this.points = points.stream().sorted().toList();
    }

    public Points(Point p, Collection<Point> points) {
        this.points = Stream.concat(Stream.of(p), points.stream()).sorted().toList();
    }

    public List<Point> getPoints() {
        return points.stream().toList();
    }

    public int size() {
        return points.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Points that) {
        return this.points.get(0).compareTo(that.points.get(0));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return points.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(" -> "));
    }
}
```

And these modifications to your class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public class FastCollinearPoints {
    public FastCollinearPoints(Point[] points) {
        checkNull(points);
        checkDuplicate(points);
        Set<Points> results = new TreeSet<>();

        for (Point p : points) {
            Map<Double, List<Point>> mapped = Arrays.stream(points)
                .collect(groupingBy(s -> p.slopeTo(s)));

            for (List<Point> rest : mapped.values()) {
                Points ps = new Points(p, rest);
                if (ps.size() >= 4) {
                    results.add(ps);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Points ps : results) {
            System.out.println(ps);
        }
    }

    // et cetera
}
```

And making reasonable assumptions about your `Point` class, I get the following results for your data sets:

8-points:

```
(0, 10000) -> (3000, 7000) -> (7000, 3000) -> (10000, 0)
(3000, 4000) -> (6000, 7000) -> (14000, 15000) -> (20000, 21000)
```

15-points:

```
(0, 10000) -> (2000, 8000) -> (8000, 2000) -> (10000, 0)
(0, 30000) -> (10000, 20000) -> (20000, 10000) -> (30000, 0)
(5000, 12000) -> (9000, 6000) -> (11000, 3000) -> (13000, 0)
(10000, 0) -> (13000, 0) -> (20000, 0) -> (30000, 0)
```

Does that help you?